# Applying PCA on the user's defined covariance matrix

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to apply principal component analysis on a covariance matrix estimated from the relationships among all individuals, see Mm in the following example. 
I will appreciate it so much if anyone can show me how to do it

Example:

```
library(BLR)
library (rrBLUP)
data(wheat)
```

Mm is the covariance matrix that I want to compute PCA

```
Mm <- A.mat(X)
```

Comment: See `?princomp` for help.

Comment: and ?prcomp. Here are some [examples](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/R_BioCondManual#TOC-Principal-Component-Analysis-PCA-).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using your dataset. I'm not sure if this is what you are after

```
pca <- prcomp(Mm, scale=T)

# Check out whats in it
str(pca)

# Prints variance summary for all principal components.
summary(pca) 

# Accesses subset of components.
summary(pca)$importance[, 1:20]

require(GGally)
ggpairs(pca$x[,1:4])
```

Comment: Martín Bel: thank you for your answer --- but what worries me is treating the covariance matrix as a regular.

Comment: @hema Why would that be a problem? Whats missing for this to be a valid answer?